# DECLARE A FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT causes ORA-00907

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl, create-table

I have a create table statement, but it's not compile,
The fk_myFirstTable CONSTRAINT cause the problem.
Someone know what wrong in the CONSTRAINT ?

I get : ORA-00907: -  "missing right parenthesis"

```
  CREATE TABLE "mySchema"."mySecondTable " 
   (    
   idNumber NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   SystemId  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   CONSTRAINT "mySecondTable _PK" PRIMARY KEY (idNumber ),
   CONSTRAINT "fk_myFirstTable" FOREIGN KEY (SystemId) REFERENCES myFirstTable(SystemId) 
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYTBS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYTBS" ;
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a stupid space in the declare line:

```
CREATE TABLE "mySchema"."mySecondTable "
```

instead of:

```
CREATE TABLE "mySchema"."mySecondTable"
```

Sorry for the lack of attention!

Answer (score 1):

The USING INDEX clause is part of the primary key constraint. I moved the foreign key constraint to after the ENABLE,.
Try this:

```
 CREATE TABLE "mySchema"."mySecondTable " 
   (    
   idNumber NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   SystemId  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   CONSTRAINT "mySecondTable _PK" PRIMARY KEY (idNumber )
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYTBS"  ENABLE,
 CONSTRAINT "fk_myFirstTable" FOREIGN KEY (SystemId) REFERENCES myFirstTable(SystemId)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYTBS" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few objections, if I may: you didn't write that code, did you? It suspiciously looks like a copy/paste from some GUI which - true - fetches all that information from dictionary and creates a *jungle*, when all you need is a *bush*.

Don't enclose Oracle objects' names into double quotes and - even worse - use mixed case within those double quotes. Otherwise, you'll have to reference them using double quotes, the same mixed case, *ALWAYS*. A true nightmare. By default, Oracle will create them using uppercase, but you can reference them using any case (lower, mixed, upper - just don't store them as such!).

- NO: "mySecondTable " - note a trailing space - horror!
- YES (as their name will be stored in UPPERCASE anyway):

  - mysecondtable
  - MYSECONDTABLE
  - mySecondTable

There's no need to specify NOT NULL for column(s) that make(s) primary key constraint; by default, they can't be NULL.

All that storage mumbo-jumbo ... phew, if this is an ordinary table we use for daily purposes, you really shouldn't take care about it and let Oracle handle those information. I agree - no problem in specifying all that *if* you know what they are. Reading your question, I think you should rely on Oracle.

Shortened, your query might/should look as follows (I'm creating the my_first_table, just to make the foreign key constraint work):

```
SQL> create table my_first_table
  2    (system_id number constraint pk_mft primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table my_second_table
  2    (id_number number constraint pk_mst primary key,
  3     system_id number constraint fk_my_first_table references my_first_table (system_id)
  4                      not null
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Can also be output of DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL

Comment: True, @Rene, thank you. Whatever it is, it is *ugly* :)